# 'logcat -s Antutu Benchmark' didn't work on commandline

Tags: android, logcat

I want to filter "Antutu Benchmark" in logcat logs. I have tried

```
logcat -s Antutu Benchmark
logcat -s Antutu\ Benchmark
```

But both of them can't work. Is it because of the space in tag? Any suggestions?
Thanks!

```
...
I/Antutu Benchmark( 1442): memory:     868
I/Antutu Benchmark( 1442): integer:     1240
I/Antutu Benchmark( 1442): float:     915
I/Antutu Benchmark( 1442): score2d:     145
I/Antutu Benchmark( 1442): score3d:     1196
I/Antutu Benchmark( 1442): database:     350
I/Antutu Benchmark( 1442): sdwrite:     85
I/Antutu Benchmark( 1442): sdread:     193
I/Antutu Benchmark( 1442): score:     4992
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following command to get all logs containing "Antutu Benchmark"

`adb logcat | grep Antutu Benchmark`

I am guessing you are using `adb` for getting logs.

Comment: I not sure why 'adb logcat -s Antutu Benchmark' can't work? Other tags without space can all be filtered successfully. It doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 0):

With recent versions of Antutu the label seems to have changed, you can now use the following:

```
logcat | grep AnTuTuBenchmarkScore
```